# Flink on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are building a stream processing job using `Flink v1.12.2` and planning to run it on a Kubernetes cluster. While referring to the official Flink documentation, we came across, primarily, two ways of submitting Flink jobs to a Kubernetes cluster, one is in `Standalone` mode and the other is in `Native` mode. We noticed that with the latter option, there are no yaml config files and looks simple. Just wondering what is the recommended mode/approach and their pros and cons. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

glad to hear you're trying out Flink on K8s!

The `Native` mode is the current recommendation for starting out on Kubernetes as it is the simplest option, like you noted. In Flink 1.13 (to be released in the coming weeks), there is added support for [specifying Pod templates](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/#pod-template). One of the drawbacks to this approach is its limited ability to integrate with CI/CD.

Some other popular approaches for a more "Kubernetes" style of running jobs (i.e. just YAML manifests) include [Lyft's Operator](https://flink-packages.org/packages/flinkk8soperator), [the Ververica Platform](https://flink-packages.org/packages/ververica-platform-community-edition) (disclaimer: I work here, on this), and [Google Cloud Platform's Operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flink-on-k8s-operator). These are all more work to set up but offer a better CI/CD story, which can help make using Flink in production less effort in the long run.

If you'd like to talk about any of these more in-depth, [the User Mailing List](https://flink.apache.org/gettinghelp.html#user-mailing-list) is full of helpful people that can weigh some of the pros/cons that apply to your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your response.